# Composer - Set local repo as the first preference

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I have just setup a local repo on my PC, and its working very well.

But the problem is when I am installing a package the composer tool checks the packagist repo first instead of my local repo. I want the local repo to be checked first. How can fix this??.

here is my global config.json

```
{
"repositories": {
    "local": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://localhost:9090"
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Satis running?

Please browse http://localhost:9090 to make that sure.

Satis needs to run properly and must list your packages, before you can work with `composer.json` (or even move things to `config.json`).

The basic guide for setting up Satis is over here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis .

If you can't get Satis running, post your `satis.json`.

---

You could try removing the key `local` from `config.json` and add `"packagist": false` instead (to disable Packagist lookups).

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "packagist": false },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://localhost:9090"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I think the solution is to combine 
- the setting `"packagist":false` on your projects 
- with `"require-dependencies": true` on your satis config.

This means that all packages you require are not fetched directly by Composer from Packagist (its off), but indirectly via the Satis server.

Satis will contact Packagist and download the packages to your Satis space (local package cache) and Composer grabs them from there.

> I cannot disable packagist since I need it for other packages.

When you allow Satis to fetch them, you can disable packagist globally for projects. The directives `require-dependencies` and `require-all` might help.

Comment: Satis is working properly. I can install packages from it. But the problem is composer checks packagist repo first. I cannot disable packagist since I need it for other packages.

I just want composer to check my local repo first and proceed packagist only if no package is found in my local repo.

Comment: I think the solution is to combine the setting "packagist:false" on your projects with "require-dependencies: true" on your satis config. This means that all packages you require are not fetched **directly** by Composer from Packagist (its off), but **indirectly** via the Satis server, which fetches them from Packagist to Satis for local caching - and then Composer grabs them from there. - "I cannot disable packagist since I need it for other packages." You can disable it, when you allow Satis  to fetch and provide them all.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice one. I will check that :).